# Error: 'Invalid Sender' when I signTransaction in bscTestnet - Web3

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask

i have the follow code:

```
const c = contract;
  const rewardsCalculatedTx = contract.methods.RewardsCalculated();
  const priveKey =
    "0xEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEExample";
  const createTransaction = await window.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    {
      from: "0xeeeexample",
      to: c._address,
      data: rewardsCalculatedTx.encodeABI(),
      gas: await rewardsCalculatedTx.estimateGas(),
    },
    priveKey
  );

  const createReceipt = await window.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
    createTransaction.rawTransaction,
    (err, txHash) => {
      console.log("err:", err, "txHash:", txHash);
    }
  );

  console.log(
    `Transaction send with hash: ${createReceipt.transactionHash}`
  );
```

The contract is previous initialized and its ok, but when I deploy this code, Im receving the follow error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.', data: {…}}

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "execution reverted: You arent the owner of this Lottery",
  "data": "0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023596f75206172656e7420746865206f776e6572206f662074686973204c6f74746572790000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
    at Object._fireError (index.js:352:1)
    at a (index.js:539:1)
    at a (util.js:688:1)
    at M (util.js:664:1)
    at b.run (browser.js:143:1)
    at p (browser.js:118:1)
```

I set the chainID: 97 but I keep getting the same error

Comment: Can you show the smart contract's code?

Comment: Sure, Im calling this function


function RewardsCalculated() public OnlyOwner{

// Code
}

The modifier is 

modifier OnlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == Owner_Contract,"You arent the owner of this Lottery");
        _;
    }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.